# How to rotate image based on an object location on a template image using Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I have 2 types of images: those that are in the right orientation, and those that are not.

I want to detect if the image is in the right orientation based on the objects positions of it.

This is an example of a right image, and I highlited some of the objects that could be used to check the right orientation:

[image]

And here is the image in the wrong orientation:

[image]

Is there any way, using python, that could do this check to rotate the image to the right orientation based on the objects location of it?

I already tried using Structural similarity index from scikit image, but this methology doesn't worked, because there are a big differences of contrasts between the images , returning wrong results of the right orientation.

Comment: You could detect the text in the image and then calculate the coordinates of the text. Then rotate the image if the text is not in the upper middle coordinates.